# ¿Como obtengo un objeto ConstraintLayout de un <include> para cambiar su tamaño?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, null, constraint-layout

Tengo un problema con el siguiente código: Quiero obtener lógicamente el ConstraintLayout de nombre **constraintFood** en una variable tipo **ConstraintLayout** para cambiar dinamicamente el alto(height), pero no lo consigo; en cambio el ImageView de nombre **imageFood** si lo obtengo sin problema en su variable correspondiente. Cabe aclarar que estoy utilizando este XML como **<>include<>** dentro del XML del activity_main, lo que lo convierte en una especie de "hijo". Espero me puedan ayudar ya que llevo un mes y no lo consigo. Muchas gracias.

XML activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <include android:id="@+id/include" layout="@layout/background_cook"></include>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

XML background_cook

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/constrainFood">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageFood"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/cook_image" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// ESTE OBJETO QUEDA NULO Y NO PUEDO CAMBIARLE NADA
        ConstraintLayout b = findViewById(R.id.constrainFood);

// A ESTE OBJETO SI SE LE PUEDE CAMBIAR LOS ATRIBUTOS
        ImageView a = findViewById(R.id.imageFood);
        a.setImageResource(R.drawable.chef_image);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Según lo dicho aquí](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html) el `id` del include sobre-escribe el id del layout, por lo tanto, haciendo esto debería funcionar: `ConstraintLayout b = findViewById(R.id.include);`  Como nota, no usaría palabras como `include` para un id. Otra cosa que podrías hacer sería no poner `id` en el `include` y referirte al elemento por su nombre real `constrainFood`. No lo he probado, pero por lógica, debería funcionar. En definitiva, el problema es que estás sobre-escribiendo el id real.

Comment: Por dios es muy lógico, si era eso. Muchas , muchas , muchas gracias :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como se indica el [blog de Android](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html), si usas un `id` al hacer `include` éste `id` va a sobre-escribir el del layout.

Por lo tanto, si lo haces así:

```
<include android:id="@+id/include" layout="@layout/background_cook"></include>
```

El `id` ya no será `constrainFood` para ese contexto, sino `include`.

En la parte programática, tendrías entonces que referirte al elemento de este modo:

```
    ConstraintLayout b = findViewById(R.id.include);
```

> ### Recomendación
>
> Evita otorgar identificadores que podrían ser palabras reservadas. En
>   lugar de `include` usa algo como `m_include` o `mInclude` o algo más
>   descriptivo, según la convención de nombre que estés usando.

También podrías no poner un `id` en el `include` y entonces referirte al elemento por su nombre original, dado que en ese caso el `id` no se va  sobre-escribir:

#### XML

```
<include layout="@layout/background_cook"></include>
```

#### Java

```
ConstraintLayout b = findViewById(R.id.constrainFood);
```